# How to restrict system internet to use only few URLs, Using Android device administration APIs

Tags: android, mdm, device-admin

I want create an app to restrict android system internet. I also want to block other applications and  Bluetooth. (Without rooting device)

How can I achieve it using android device admin APIs?

Please let me know in case of any other solutions for enforcing such system level restriction.

Comment: check this out:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729872/programmatically-enable-android-device-administration?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

These features are accessible to Profile owners and Device Owners. I would request you to Read about [Google EMM](https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements) and [Device Provisioning](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/provision). Google allows you to use their EMM API to manage devices via a Google EMM Community account. Alternativly you can use various 3rd party EMM or MDM solutions like [Kardamom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.appslab.kardamom) or [IBM MaaS360](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fiberlink.maas360.android.control)